# Using Local and Remote Variable in SSH

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

I have written a shell script which SSH to a remote host and does some processing. The code that executes remotely has to to use the local variables which are read from  the properties file. My code is as below. The below code is not executed properly. Its giving an error that

```
-printf: unknown primary or command.
```

Please help me with this.

Note: datadir, username and ftphostname are defined in properties file.

```
. config.properties
ssh $username@$ftphostname << EOF
filelist=;
filelist=($(find "$datadir" -type f -printf "%T@ %p\n"| sort -n | head -5 | cut -f2- -d" "));
filecount=\${#filelist[@]};
while [ \${#filelist[@]} -gt 0 ]; do
checkCount=;
 filesSize=$(wc -c \${filelist[@]}|tail -n 1 | cut -d " " -f1) ;

     if [ "\$filesSize" ==  "\$fileSizeStored" ]; then
            fileSizeStored=0;
            printf "\n*********** \$(date) ************* " >> /home/chisan/logs/joblogs.log;
            echo "Moved below files" >> /home/joblogs.log;
            for i in "\${filelist[@]}"
            do
      #     echo "file is \$i"
                    checkCount=0;
                    mv \$i /home/outputdirectory/;
                    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                      echo "File Moved to the server: \$i" >> /home/joblogs.log;
                    else
                      echo "Error: Failed to move file: \$i" >> /home/joblogs.log;
                    fi
            done
            filelist=($(find "$datadir" -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -n | head -5 | cut -f2- -d" "));
     else
                    ((checkCount+=1));
                    sleep 4;
                    fileSizeStored=\$filesSize;
     fi
   done
   EOF
```

But this one works

```
#ssh to remote system and sort the files and fetch the files which are copied first(based on modification time)
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@server 'filelist=($(find /home/data -type f - printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort -n | head -5 | cut -f2- -d" "));
# filelist array variable holds the file names which have the oldest modification date.
#check the directory until it has atleast one file.
while [ ${#filelist[@]} -gt 0 ]; do
filesSize=$(wc -c "${filelist[@]}"|tail -n 1 | cut -d " " -f1) ;
#filesSize contains the total size of the files that are in the filelist array.
if [ -e "$HOME/.storeFilesSize" ]; then
     fileSizeStored=$(cat "$HOME/.storeFilesSize");
     if [ "$filesSize" ==  "$fileSizeStored" ]; then
            echo "Moved below files" >> /home/joblogs.log;
            for i in "${filelist[@]}"
            do
                    mv "$i" /home/dmpdata1 &>/dev/null;
                    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                     echo "File Moved to the server: $i" >>/home/joblogs.log;
                    else
                     echo "Error: Failed to move file: $i" >>/home/joblogs.log;
                    fi
            done
            filelist=($(find /home/data -type f -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort -n | head -5 | cut -f2- -d" "));
     else
                    sleep 4;
                    echo "$filesSize" > "$HOME/.storeFilesSize";
     fi

else
     echo "creating new file";

     echo "$filesSize" > "$HOME/.storeFilesSize";
 fi
done'
```

Comment: on your first go around the while loop, `$fileSizeStored` won't be defined yet, because you only define it near the end of the loop innards.  Plus, have you done any basic debugging yourself, e.g. start yanking/commenting lines to see which one's causing the problem?

Comment: You're escaping exactly the wrong things. Your heredoc must have `\$remote` and `$local`, where `remote` is a variable on the remote.

Comment: But you also need to be consistent: you have `filelist` both escaped and unescaped.

Comment: Thank you mark. I have made the changes you suggested.

Comment: @MarcB you don't need to instantiate variables in bash scripts, default value is empty. Thus the test will return `false` on the first try, but `true` on the second. According to that, `filelist=;` and all empty instantitions in OP's script is also not needed

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Now I have made the escaping consistent. i.e escaped the remote variables and unescaped the local variables.

Comment: `-printf: unknown primary or command`: That does not seem to have anything to do with variables but with some strange old version of `find`. What system is the server?

Comment: you need to escape the `$` before the find as well, if you want it to be executed remotely. As of now, the scripts execute the `find` command on the local machine

Comment: @JanHudec: I dont think this is an issue with find because it works fine if I just hardcode the datadir variable. I have updated the working code(by hardcoding) as well. Now I want to supply the datadir from local system.

Comment: You have an extraneous space between the hyphen and `printf`. In `find`, curiously, this action is technically an option.

Comment: @Ploutox Thanks: Now I have got the script running by escaping the $ before find command. Thanks. Even though my program is running fine after making changes its throwing a warning:   "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.". I tried with ssh -t -t as well but to no solution.

Comment: Try with `-T` instead. Is your remote shell restricted ? (ie, do you get your error like this : `-rbash : Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal`)

Answer (score 0):

I will not answer directly (ie, not with your specific needs and actions), but give a generic possibility and how to use local and remote variables :

Your master script should create a "specific script", locally.
And then copy it over and run it remotely (with additionnal arguments if needed)

Generic example of Master script :

```
#local Master script: This script creates a local script, 
#                     and then copy it to remotehost and start it

#Some local variables will be defined here. 
#They can be used below, and will be replaced by their value locally
localvar1="...."   
localvar2="...."  

#now we create the script 
cat > /tmp/localscript_to_be_copied_to_remote.sh <<EOF 
#remote_script

for i in ..... ; do 
    something ; 
    somethingelse
done
......
.....
EOF

#in the above, each time you used "$localvar1" or "$localvar2", the script
# /tmp/localscript_to_be_copied_to_remote.sh will instead have their values, 
# as the local shell will replace them on the fly during the cat > ... <<EOF .
# if you want to have some remotevariable "as is" (and not as their local value) in the script,
# write them as "\$remotevariable" there, instead of "$remotevariable", so the local shell  
# won't interpret them during the 'cat', and the script will receive "$remotevariable" 
# as is, instead of its local value.

#then you copy the script:
scp -p /tmp/localscript_to_be_copied_to_remote.sh  user@remotehost:/some/dir/name.sh

#and you run it:
# UNCOMMENT the line below ONLY when /tmp/localscript_to_be_copied_to_remote.sh is correct!
#   ssh user@remotehost  "/some/dir/name.sh"  #+ maybe some parameters as well

#end of local Master script.
```

You then run "local Master script" and have it create the tmp file locally (which you can check to make sure it is supposed to be like this on the remote host), and then copy it remotely and execute it.

Specific example of master script :

```
#!/bin/bash
local1="/tmp /var /usr /home"  # this will be the default name of the dirs (on the remote host)
                               # that the script will print the size of (+ any additionnal parameters)

cat > /tmp/printsizes.bash <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
for dir in $local1 "\$@" ; do
   du -ks "\$dir"
done
EOF

scp -p /tmp/printsizes.bash  user@remotehost:/tmp/print_dir_sizes.bash

ssh user@remotehost "/tmp/print_dir_sizes.bash /etc /root"
```

This (weird...) example will create a LOCAL script containing:

```
#!/bin/bash
for dir in /tmp /var /usr /home "$@" ; do
   du -ks "$dir"
done
```

And will execute it with:

```
ssh user@remotehost "/tmp/print_dir_sizes.bash /etc /root"
```

so it will do remotely:

```
for dir in /tmp /var /usr /home /etc /root ; do 
   du -ks "$dir"
done
```

I hope it helps to see how to use local and remote variables...